# Batch File to Delete Columns in csv

Tags: batch-file

Im sure this has been answered but I can't find a simple solution. I receive a very large csv file daily and if I open it, it crashes my computer.  It has over 38 columns.   How do I delete  columns 7-25,28- 38.  Its the same file everyday.  Columns are the same...just more rows. Hoping to use a batch file and just execute it before i open it.

I tried other peoples batch files, but it didnt work.  There are no special characters or delimiters. Just to much unnecessary data for me to analyze.

Comment: What do you mean by very large? 38 fields doesn't sound large to me. Also which program/software are you using to open/view your CSV file? If, as you say, there are no special characters, and the file is poperly delimited and formed, there is no reason for a plain text file to crash a computer. The software you're using to open the CSV file is more likely to be the cause of the crash, not the CSV file itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
(@for /f "tokens=1-6,25*" %%g in (filename) do @for /f "tokens=1,2,13*" %G in ("%%n") do @echo %%g,%%h,%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%G,%%H.%%J)>newfile
```

should deliver those columns

(as a batch file - to execute directly from the prompt, replace each `%%` with `%`